# GitHub How To Get Last Active Deployment

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions

My goal is to find the latest successful deployment of a repository in GitHub. There is no query to filter deployment history in GitHub REST API.

I didn't want to call two different GET Endpoints and then aggregate their results by using the backend so I wrote a GraphQL query. But in the query, I couldn't find a way to filter statuses as active. Any opinion would be great

## GraphQL query

```
query ($repo_owner: String!, $repo_name: String!, $environment: String!) {
  repository(owner: $repo_owner, name: $repo_name) {
    deployments(environments: [$environment], first: 10, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        state
        ref {
            name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Result

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "deployments": {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "state": "FAILURE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "2"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "ACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "state": "INACTIVE",
                        "ref": {
                            "name": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have active status only.